# Multi-Tenant with shared database and discriminator column

Tags: java, database, rest, multi-tenant, quarkus

Hibernate Multi-tenant Shared Database (discriminator column) until now still not implemented.

I'm working on a Quarkus RestEasy JAX-RS endpoint.
I want to use a Multi-Tenant Architecture (not separate database or separate schema but shared database with discriminator column like tenantId). Quarkus also only support separate database and separate schema like Hibernate.

So, how can I implement a custom resolver to write my endpoint resources methods (get, post, put, delete) according to a tenantId?

I thought about an interceptor or filter, but I have no idea how to implement it with Quarkus.

The idea is (SaaS):

- Create customer account (set him a tenant ID)
- When a user login, data are fetched according to his tenantId.

The use case:

Tenant1 sends HTTP request containing his tenantId, from endpoint resources,  get the tenantId and implement  save(), getAll(), get(), delete() methods according to the current tenantId value, and so every tenant will only get or add his own data.

Other possibility:

Is it possible to use a separate schema and write a service (manager dashboard) which can pickup data from all tenants schemas?

Example:

- Tenant1 = StackOverflow US (number of employees = 50) (employee table in SCHEMA 1)
- Tenant2 = StackOverflow France (number of employees = 30) (employee table in SCHEMA 2)
- StackOverFlow Global Manager Dashboard (Total employees = 80, sum of *Schema 1 employee table* and *Schema 2 employee table*) and he can also have statistics by subsidiary.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus currently only support separate database and separate schema for multi-tenancy, see https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multitenancy

What you want is Partitioned (discriminator) data, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4808

So, if you can use separate schema, it's doable OOTB with Quarkus.

For your global dashboard, you can for example create a view on a dedicated schema that is the union of the corresponding table on "by tenant" schema.

Answer (score 0):

In Quarkus 3, Hibernate 6.0 introduces a new feature called `@TenantId`, which facilitates separating tenants based on a specific column (discriminator). To utilize this feature in Quarkus, you'll need to implement a `TenantResolver` interface. This interface includes a method called `resolveTenantId`, where you'll need to devise a logic to extract the tenant ID from the incoming request and return it. This tenant ID will then be utilized by the `@TenantId` annotation for filtering purposes. When using `@TenantId`, it should be placed over the column you intend to use for filtering

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.tenant.TenantResolver;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

@PersistenceUnitExtension 
@RequestScoped 
public class CustomTenantResolver implements TenantResolver {

    @Inject
    RoutingContext context;

    @Override
    public String getDefaultTenantId() {
        return "base";
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveTenantId() {
        String path = context.request().path();
        String[] parts = path.split("/");

        if (parts.length == 0) {
            // resolve to default tenant config
            return getDefaultTenantId();
        }

        return parts[1];
    }

}


@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    @TenantId
    private String tenantId;

}
```

Create one base entity like the above one and use, it would be better insted of duplicating the code in all entity